# g++ crashed when I tried to compile a program with ONE LINE

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

My program is this:

```
#include <iostream>
```

That's it. That's the entire program, just one line.

I tried to compile it with this:

```
g++ CVB--OpenPic--00.cpp -o cv
```

and I got this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've compiled dozens of other `.cpp` files over the past few weeks, and many, many other programs. What exactly is happening *here*?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined `main()` function in your program.

As said in error:

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

PS:

This is not crash of `g++`, it just shows error message when can't find definition of `main()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `g++` did not crash. It has just and rightfully emitted some error message, then it completed successfully (with a failure exit code). Actually the error message is given by the linker `ld` (which  `g++` has run after running the `cc1plus` compiler proper).

Your code does not has any `main` function (which is the function that starts execution, after construction of static variables, in C++), so you cannot compile it into an executable.

BTW, you should *always* compile your code with all warnings & debug info, so use

```
g++ -Wall -g CVB--OpenPic--00.cpp -o cv
```

Once you did debug your program (using the `gdb` debugger) you might want to benchmark it. Then ask the compiler to optimize (e.g. by adding `-O2` option to `g++`).

Notice that order of arguments to `g++` matters a big lot.

Once your program becomes larger and made of *several* [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (e.g. several `.cpp` files, probably all `#include`-ing your header file[s]), you'll want to use a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). Learn also to use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) and a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Yeah, I got that now. And I don't use a command to compile, I use a script: https://gist.github.com/Rich700000000000/afacd46adad81f73b2162259a78af29b

Comment: In your case, you don't need any script, and you don't need to `rm` the binary before `g++`. But your script has forgotten `-Wall` & `-g`